# why this two type casting makes different output?

Tags: c, pointers

I am new to programming,
I have tried to find out the size of the buffer.

what internally happens while type cast to the character `(char*)` or `(int*)` pointer?

`(int*)((&var)+1)-(int*)(&var)`

`(char*)((&var)+1)-(char*)(&var)`

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
char testBuff[10]="testsize";
int var[10]={10,20,30};

int d=(int*)((&var)+1)-(int*)(&var);

printf("%d",d);
int d1=(char*)((&var)+1)-(char*)(&var);

printf("%d",d1);
}
```

Comment: You abuse *undefined behavior*, so the behavior will vary. Just don't write bad code like that.

Comment: first, look at the basics, you have declared a variable of int data type twice, 'int d'

Comment: my question is any advantage of type case an address  to char* pointer? because the correct answer i got using "char*"

Comment: Re "*because the correct answer i got using `char*`*", This implies you are trying to achieve something specific. Perhaps you should tell us what that is and ask how to achieve it.

Comment: '#define my_sizeof(type) (char *)(&type+1)-(char*)(&type)' , its from geeksforgeeks,why they typecast to char*

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude where is the UB ?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am not sure if it can be applied in this case (array decayed references where type is the same as an array element).  IMO it is well defined.

Answer (score 1):

The actual values of `var`, `&var`, `(char*)&var` and `(int*)&var` are all the same, the memory address of the array of `int`s. Try printing them out.

The reason it behaves this way is that `var` is of the type `int[10]` as far as the compiler is concerned, so it can keep track of the size of the array. `sizeof(var)` will return 40 bytes, which is correct (10 ints of size 4 bytes). However, the underlying value of the variable is really a pointer, `int*`. Getting the address of the array using `&var` simply returns this value.

So both `int d=(int*)((&var)+1)-(int*)(&var);` and `int d1=(char*)((&var)+1)-(char*)(&var);` calculate the difference between the same two pointers. The only reason they return a different value is the size of the type they refer to. The difference calculated is 40 bytes, which is 40 `char`s, or 10 `int`s.

Answer (score 0):

This post was writteny to correct @mouviciel answer.

```
int var[10]={10,20,30};
```

`var` is an array of 10 `int` elements. It decays to the pointer of type `int *` referencing first element of the array

`&var` has the type of `int (*)[10]` (pointer to the array 10 int elements). It references the same area in memory as decayed `var`. **IT IS NOT POINTER TO POINTER**

Answer (score 0):

These two are the same:

```
printf("%p %p \n", &var,    &var+1);   // +1 whole var array 
printf("%p %p \n", &var[0], &var[10]); // [10] is first above var
```

The `+ 1` is tricky because it is not the usual `var+n` pointer arithmetic. It applies to a non existing array of var-arrays.

To subtract directly pointers as byte values (no * in cast):

```
printf("%ld\n", (long)&var[10] - (long)&var[0]);  
printf("%ld\n", (long)(&var+1) - (long)&var);
```

The second version still has the `+1` of a full var array. This gives the size of var[] (40). Same as with `(char*)`.

A longer type, this time with `*`:

```
printf("%ld\n", (long double*)(&var + 1) - (long double*)&var);  // only 2
```

As a long double array the adresses are only 2 full elements apart.

---

A more normal way to see (one past) the end of var:

```
printf("%p\n",  (void*)var + sizeof var);
```

The cast is important, otherwise it adds 40 * 4.

---

But all this is borderline and vain in the end. To see how many elements of Type X would fit into an existing array:

```
printf("%f\n",  (float)sizeof var / sizeof(long double));
```

gives 2.5 and an indication that var[] is not allocated/aligned for this type (if you need that hint). But the expression itself is much simpler, even with the cast to float.

---

> to find out the size of the buffer

What are you calling *buffer* here?

Answer (score 0):

Pointer arithmetic is always done in the units of the elements being pointed to.

Subtracting two `int` pointers will give different results from subtracting two `char` pointers, because the element type is different.

Assuming that `int` is a 32-bit type (which it commonly is) then the result with the `int` pointers should be one quarter compared to the `char` pointer subtraction (the `int` subtraction should give `10` as a result, while `char` should result in `40`).

With that said, if you want the size in bytes of an actual array, then use `sizeof`. If you want the number of elements, divide the size of the full array with the size of one element.

Answer (score -1):

Since char and int have different memory allocation size the value because of such typecasting will be different.

You can see by printing the following messages:

```c
printf("%d\n",sizeof(int));
printf("%d\n",sizeof(char));

printf("%d\n",(char*)(&var));
printf("%d\n",(char*)((&var)+1));
```

Also, **var itself is the pointer to an array**.

&var will be having the address of that pointer. So if you are doing any arithmetic operation it will not be done over int var array but aver memory address space.

To actually access array elements use:

```c
printf("%d\n",*(char*)(var));
printf("%d\n",*(char*)((var)+1));
printf("%d\n",*(int*)(var));
printf("%d\n",*(int*)((var)+1));
```

Comment: `var` is not a pointer to an array, and `&var` is not the address of a pointer. `var` is an array, and `&var` is the address of the array.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was trying to say. Since in the question operations were done on the address. That is why I had added those print statements to show what I was trying to say.

Answer (score -2):

`var[]` (with square brackets) is a variable of type *array of ints*. `var` (without square brackets) is a pointer to that array. `&var` is a pointer to that pointer. Arithmetic operations on pointers to pointers (`(&var)+1`) might not be what you intended to do.

Comment: That's not true. The type of `var` is `int (*)[10]`, an array of ten `int`s. You can verify this using `sizeof`. A possible value for `sizeof(var)` is 40, far larger than the size of the pointer you claim it is.